# How to POST json request on web server using HttpUrlConnection in android?

Tags: android, json

I am new and trying to send json request to web server and trying to get json response using httpUrlConnection but its giving http 402 status, i am failing to get any solution any senior please help, my code is as follow

```
URL url_webServer = new URL("http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetTrackerInfo");

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url_webServer.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
//urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
//11urlConnection.connect();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConnection.connect();

JSONObject jsonObject_webJsonRequest = new JSONObject();
jsonObject_webJsonRequest.put("tid", "1");

outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
outputStreamWriter.write((jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString()));

//jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString().getBytes();
//outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString().getBytes());

//clean up
outputStreamWriter.flush();
outputStreamWriter.close();

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    bufferedReader.close();

    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
} else {
    String response = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
}I am new and trying to send json request to web server and trying to get json response using httpUrlConnection but its giving http 402 status, i am failing to get any solution any senior please help, my code is as follow

URL url_webServer = new URL("http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetTrackerInfo");

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url_webServer.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
//urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
//11urlConnection.connect();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConnection.connect();

JSONObject jsonObject_webJsonRequest = new JSONObject();
jsonObject_webJsonRequest.put("tid", "1");

outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
outputStreamWriter.write((jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString()));

//jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString().getBytes();
//outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString().getBytes());

//clean up
outputStreamWriter.flush();
outputStreamWriter.close();

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    bufferedReader.close();

    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
} else {
    String response = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)  **status code 402 means**

> PaymentRequired 402
>
> The parameter to this message gives a specification of charging
>   schemes acceptable. The client may retry the request with a suitable
>   ChargeTo header.

This probably means server on which you are hosting your web service requires some payment to be done

Comment: i am redoing this app which working fine and its web api test tool is also working fine

Answer (score 0):

Call this method

```
public void senddatatoserver() {
    //function in the activity that corresponds to the layout button
    JSONObject post_dict = new JSONObject();

    try {
        post_dict.put("Key1", value1);
    post_dict.put("Key2", value2);
    post_dict.put("Key3", value3);
        post_dict.put("Key4", value4);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (post_dict.length() > 0) {
        new SendJsonDataToServer().execute(String.valueOf(post_dict));

    }
}
```

Then call the asynctask like this

```
class SendJsonDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String JsonResponse = null;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(TwoAnswerScreenActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();


        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String JsonDATA = params[0];
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // is output buffer writter
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//set headers and method
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(JsonDATA);
// json data
//                Log.e("Response", JsonResponse + "");
                writer.close();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//input stream
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
                Log.e("Response", JsonResponse + "");
//response data
                Log.i("Tag", JsonResponse);
                //send to post execute

                return JsonResponse;
//                return null;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Tag", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


            if (JsonResponse != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //Your success code
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

402 status might mean that the service is charged and not free but that should not be used, most commonly it would mean that you have exceeded the request limit. [4xx Client Error - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). But you could try something like this.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    // making HTTP request
    try {

        String req = URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject_webJsonRequest.toString(), "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetTrackerInfo");

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); //
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(req.getBytes().length);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.print(req);
        out.close();

        try {
            // parsing the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(line); // optional
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            string = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }

        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //parse the response
```

Comment: i redoing this app, it is working fine on iOS, and on web api test tool its working fine.